# How do I create spacing in between JButtons?

Tags: java, whitespace, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create little main menu for a simple scheduling program right now, but I am having a bit of difficulty having some space in between the buttons. They just stick right next to each other, I would like there to be a gap between each button.

I have tried to use the weightx, weighty commands but nothing seems to change.
I would like to have some blank space between the edges of the GUI and the sides of the buttons, and also between each button.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Scheduler {

JButton VDay, VWeek, Task, Exit;
JFrame wframe, dframe, tframe;

JLabel head;




public void CreateFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");     

    ButtonListener btnlst = new ButtonListener();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    head = new JLabel("The Plain Scheduler");
    panel.add(head, c);
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridheight = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    VDay = new JButton("View Day");
    panel.add(VDay, c);
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.gridheight = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    VWeek = new JButton("View Week");
    panel.add(VWeek,c);
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridheight = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    Task = new JButton("Assign/Edit Tasks");
    panel.add(Task, c);
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    panel.add(Exit, c);

    VDay.addActionListener(btnlst);
    VWeek.addActionListener(btnlst);
    Task.addActionListener(btnlst);
    Exit.addActionListener(btnlst);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    scheduler.CreateFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `GridBagConstraints#insets`

Comment: `I am having a bit of difficulty having some space in between the buttons`  - Once again the tutorial has an example. Notice the space between button 4 and button 5. `I would like to have some blank space between the edges` - this might be better accomplished by using a `Border` on the panel. The tutorial has a section on `How to Use Borders`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry but could you give an example code of just how it would look? I tried "c.insets = 2;" but I got an error saying "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Insets"

Comment: `I tried "c.insets = 2;"` - is that what the tutorial does?

Comment: ^-- Or the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#insets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GridBagConstraints#insets` to define the amount of spacing/padding which is added to a cell, for example...

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Scheduler {

    JButton VDay, VWeek, Task, Exit;
    JFrame wframe, dframe, tframe;

    JLabel head;

    public void CreateFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = .25;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0);
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        head = new JLabel("The Plain Scheduler");
        panel.add(head, c);
        VDay = new JButton("View Day");
        panel.add(VDay, c);
        VWeek = new JButton("View Week");
        panel.add(VWeek, c);
        Task = new JButton("Assign/Edit Tasks");
        panel.add(Task, c);
        Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        panel.add(Exit, c);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
                scheduler.CreateFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```